# How to download THIS file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, download

The `javascript` inside my page needs to download the small text file (just a small JSON Array)  that resides in the following location:

http://dadosabertos.rio.rj.gov.br/apiTransporte/apresentacao/rest/index.cfm/obterPosicoesDaLinha/410

The MIME type of the document is `application/json`.
I tried with a `XMLHttpRequest` but I got an error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://dados[...]/410. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I googled this, and the solutions pointed to CORS and to change things on the server side, something I cannot do.

Is there any way to retrieve this content with javascript (and only javascript)?

Thanks!
L.

**EDIT**

Following @naresh advice, I am trying with JSONP. I added these lines to my page, but nothing happens (not even a console error):

```
var source = "http://dados[...]/409";
script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = source + '?callback=downloadLinha';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

My function `downloadLinha(data)` is just `alert(data)`.

**EDIT 2**

I contacted the server administrator, and, to my surprise, they fixed the problem in a couple of hours! I didn't expect they would even answer. So my actual problem is solved, but I could not find an answer without the administrator intervention.

Anyway, thanks A LOT to all that tried to help!

Comment: **"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."**

Comment: You can also use JSONP. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @naresh: It seems you're my only hope... :o) I read the link you sent me, and trying to implement it in my page, without luck. Nothing happens? Please, see my EDIT.

Comment: JSONP has to be supported by the server/service. And it seems that service doesn't. (what you are forgetting in the code snippet above is adding the `script` element to the document. But as I said, that wouldn't solve your overall problem).

Comment: @LuisA.Florit As mentioned by Felix, JSONP has to be supported by server. Can you check with the service provider about that?

Comment: @FelixKling The second line of the snippet adds the script, no?

Comment: @naresh: It's a city council web page. I can ask, but they probably won't answer anything.

Comment: No, it *creates* the element, it doesn't add it to the document. You are missing `documen.body.appendChild(script);`, or something like this. But as I said, it won't help because the service doesn't seem to support JSONP, at least not via the "standard" query parameter `callback`.

Comment: @FelixKling @naresh Oops! You're right, sorry, I fixed the snippet. And it seems there's some hope. I got an error in the javascript console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : 409:1` So it thinks 409 is a script? Anyway, when I click on the `409:1`, it shows me the content I want to download! So it seems it's there somehow...

Comment: Yep, the content is interpreted as JavaScript script because you are using `script` tag to load it. There is nothing you can do to get the raw content though. That's why I'm saying (repeatedly) that it won't solve your problem.

Comment: @FelixKling: I see... This is public data to be used freely by developers, so there "should" be an easy way to get the data? In the site, they say: "It is also available a REST flux, that can be accessed via http, and provides a set of data as a JSON Array". :o(

Comment: @LuisA.Florit If you cannot use CORS & JSONP, you can a write a small server-side program, which fetches data from that city council web page. You can then easily access your sever-side resource from your javascript. (whenever u invoke your server-side resource, it just fetches content from that external webpage and returns the same)

Comment: @naresh: In fact, I could use wget or curl or something to retrieve the content (that works fine). I think this is more or less what you're suggesting, no? Anyway, the `XMLHttpRequest` usual technique works perfectly inside a `webview` of an `Android` app. Any idea why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what @RobertHarvey said, the lack of a header doesn't let you access it... Via Chrome, that is. You might still be able to access it using this handy tool called anyorigin.

Check it out: http://anyorigin.com/

Comment: anyorigin.com cannot retrieve that page either. It outputs: `400 Requested MIME type not available`

Comment: It's in the original post.

Comment: @JoeFrambach: Please see my EDIT 2. I solved the issue contacting the system administrator! This is a miracle... Anyway, thanks a lot to all of you that tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, no can do! If I could, I would hava javascript silently load the contents of `www.yourbank.com` via AJAX and read whatever it can. Don't you think this is a dangerous feature with the prevalence of auto-login on the web?

You can use a proxy server, which will work as long as the target file does not depend on user-specific cookies, headers, etc.

Comment: I tried your proxy suggestion through a `.htaccess` file, but I get internal server errors. How to implement this?

Comment: Apache can't so it on its own. What server-side language do you prefer? Here's a proxy server in node: http://www.catonmat.net/http-proxy-in-nodejs/